# extracting decimal value from a character in a Z3 string

Tags: string, z3, smt

Let s1 be an arbitrary string in Z3Str.
I can check if the third character in it is a lower case letter:

```
(declare-const s1 String)
(assert (= s1 "74b\x00!!###$$"))
(assert (str.in.re (str.at s1 2) (re.range "a" "z")))
(check-sat)
(get-value (s1))
```

Now suppose it really is, and I want to replace that third letter
with its upper case (the new string s2 will contain the replaced version). Inspired by standard programming languages,
I might be tempted to do something like this:

```
(declare-const s1 String)
(declare-const s2 String)
(declare-const b1 Bool)
(assert (= s1 "74b\x00!!###$$"))
(assert (= b1 (str.in.re (str.at s1 2) (re.range "a" "z"))))
(assert (= (str.substr s2 0 2) (str.substr s1 0 2)))
(assert (= (str.substr s2 3 8) (str.substr s1 3 8)))
(assert (= (str.len s2) (str.len s1)))
(assert (= (str.at s2 2) (ite b1 (- (str.at s1 2) 32) (str.at s1 2))))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;; 32 = 'a'-'A'
(check-sat)
(get-value (s1 s2 b1))
```

But, of course, this doesn't work because of the types:

```
(error "line 9 column 52: Sort mismatch at argument #1 for function 
(declare-fun - (Int Int) Int) supplied sort is String")
```

Is there any **straight forward** way of manipulating the decimal
value of a character in a Z3 string? I mean other than a giant switch-case on **all** lower case letters ... There seems to be some hope, because the API does support "\x61" as an alternative representation of "a". Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works:

```
(declare-const s1 String)
(declare-const s2 String)
(declare-const b1 Bool)
(assert (= s1 "74b\x00!!###$$"))
(assert (= b1 (str.in.re (str.at s1 2) (re.range "a" "z"))))
(assert (= (str.substr s2 0 2) (str.substr s1 0 2)))
(assert (= (str.substr s2 3 8) (str.substr s1 3 8)))
(assert (= (str.len s2) (str.len s1)))

(declare-const subSecElt (_ BitVec 8))
(declare-const eltUpCase (_ BitVec 8))
(assert (= (bvsub subSecElt #x20) eltUpCase))
(assert (= (seq.unit subSecElt) (str.at s1 2)))
(assert (= (str.at s2 2) (ite b1 (seq.unit eltUpCase) (str.at s1 2))))

(check-sat)
(get-value (s1 s2 b1))
```

It would indeed be nice if this can be simplified further, though I don't see an easy way to do that since the API doesn't seem to allow accessing the elements directly from a sequence. It lets you get subsequences, but not elements, which is what you really need here: Note that a subsequence of length 1 is different than the underlying element at that position, which explains the rightful type-error you got.

This is the answer I get for this query:

```
sat
((s1 "74b\x00!!###$$")
 (s2 "74B\x00!!###$$")
 (b1 true))
```

Comment: Using Z3 4.5.1 I got the wrong value for s2 (lower case g): ((s1 ...) (s2 "74g\x00!!###$$") (b1 ...))

Comment: I updated the answer with the response I get, which seems correct. The string solver has been going through many changes, so you might want to get a more recent copy of Z3 from here: 
https://github.com/Z3Prover/bin/tree/master/nightly

Comment: Still no go even with the nightly build. I've added a watch on the auxiliary variables  subSecElt and eltUpCase and they *do* have the expected values ... However, I keep getting the wrong value for s2 (lower case o): sat
((s1 ...)
 (s2 "74o\x00!!###$$")
 (b1 ...)
 (subSecElt #x62)
 (eltUpCase #x42))

Comment: I just did a fresh Z3 build and it works just fine for me. I don't think it would matter, but I'm on a Mac. What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using UBUNTU 14.04.5 ... Here is the command line I'm running from z3/build:    ./z3 smt.string_solver=z3str3 -smt2 example.txt

Comment: The command line I ran from z3/build was wrong: ./z3 **smt.string_solver=z3str3 -smt2 example.txt** ... I've changed it to: **./z3 -smt2 example.txt** and now everything works!

Comment: That sure seems to be a bug with the z3str solver. You should report it in the z3 bug tracker so they can address it as necessary: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: Issue was reported to [GitHub/Z3Prover/z3/issues](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1331)