# Z3 sort conversion: (one character) String to (length 8) bitvector

Tags: string, z3

Referring to a previously asked SO question about [extracting the decimal value from a Z3 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522705/extracting-decimal-value-from-a-character-in-a-z3-string), I know that **converting a BitVec8 to a one character string is possible**. For example, running this query:

```
(declare-const s String)
(declare-const someBV8 (_ BitVec 8))
(assert (= (str.len s) 6))

(assert (= someBV8 #x62))
(assert (= (seq.unit someBV8) (str.at s 2)))
(assert (= (seq.unit someBV8) (str.at s 3)))
(assert (= (seq.unit someBV8) (str.at s 4)))

(check-sat)
(get-value (s))
```

gives the following output:

```
sat
((s "\x00\x00bbb\x00"))
```

I wanted to know if the opposite conversion exists too? **Is it possible to convert a one character string to a BitVec8?** Something like str2bv:

```
(declare-const s String)
(declare-const someBV8 (_ BitVec 8))
(assert (= (str.len s) 6))

(assert (= someBV8 #x62))
(assert (= someBV8 (str2bv (str.at s 2))))
(assert (= someBV8 (str2bv (str.at s 3))))
(assert (= someBV8 (str2bv (str.at s 4))))

(check-sat)
(get-value (s))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, but it's neither easy nor very effective. See the discussion here: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1302

If this is a showstopper for you, I suggest you reopen that ticket and provide some feedback. That way the z3 folks might add the required functionality directly to z3.