# In z3 How do I get the upper of a string in?

Tags: z3, z3py

I want to assert that *upper* of my string variable equals a string value. E.g

```
> v = z3.String('var')
> v.upper() == z3.StringVal('HELLO')
```

However, I do not see a way to get upper from z3's [string API](https://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/sequences). How do I accomplish this?

I find two similar questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53808101/defining-constraints-in-z3-using-boolean-operators) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522705/extracting-decimal-value-from-a-character-in-a-z3-string) which seems painful. Is this still the state of the art?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's the state of the art. There's no other way to do it using the string API provided by z3.

Note that this is a problem for both strings and sequences, and the crux of the matter is that there's no API to access the "element" at a position. (In Z3, strings are just sequences of bit-vectors of width 8.)

A request was filed a long time ago for z3 to add this API: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/1302

You might want to voice your request there so they might be inclined to add support!

(Note that some of the higher-level APIs hide that complexity from the user, by giving an easy way to access to the element at position. Here's how it's done in the SBV library: https://github.com/LeventErkok/sbv/blob/master/Data/SBV/List.hs#L135-L171. But it's a lot of work for something so simple that I wish the underlying solver just supported.)